# Fedora Updates from LAN

Tags: fedora, local-area-network, update

I have installed 10 Desktops with Fedora 13 Goddard in an enterprise network, for these desktops all the fedora updates are happening from individual machines thru the internet repository, where we like to have the updates downloaded once to a local repository and from there the rest of desktops can update. How can we do this ?

Thanks in advance

Mick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an internal yum repository is incredibly easy to do. In an overview, the steps are

1. Archive all of the rpm files using rsync (or manually select which RPMs you want, and put them in the directory)
2. Run the 'createrepo' command on the directory
3. Make the directory accessible via a web server

For rsync, you  basically take a look at the [mirror list](http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist), select one that lists rsync as an available option, and use the command:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -avrt --exclude=debug/ \
      rsync://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/fedora/linux  \
      /path/to/target/directory
```

There is some existing documentation on a piece of software called [MirrorManager](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Infrastructure/MirrorManager), but I have never used it. It sounds like it should works fine, and maybe someone else can speak to that.

There's also a useful page in the Fedora documentation wiki with a section on [How can someone make a private mirror](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Infrastructure/Mirroring#How_can_someone_make_a_private_mirror.3F).

---

Incidentally, since this is an enterprise network, have you given thought to providing desktops with CentOS, rather than Fedora? The length of support is much longer, and you're dealing with much more stable software.

It's definitely possible to maintain an [internal repo for CentOs](http://www.howtoforge.com/creating_a_local_yum_repository_centos) as well.

I do it for my servers, and if there are any packages that I need, I just put them on my local repo and install them, rather than using a large repo that I can't control, like EPEL.

Comment: Incredibly helpful reply, thank a ton…

I typically use CentOS for server but these desktops are typically used for PHP and Web Designing, do your prefer CentOS than fedora, please advise…

Thanks again…

Comment: Hi oraklecorp - Personally, I use Ubuntu, but I'm one of 2 linux-on-the-desktop users in the company. If I had to support linux desktops, I would absolutely use CentOS over Fedora, if just for the lengthened support from the people who make the OS. They're very similar. The primary difference is that CentOS has fewer software selections by default, but that can be fixed once you have your own repo (or you can enable EPEL: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Comment: Thank You So Much Again Matt, will try this and let you know... Awesome peice of suggestion.